# start countdown timer after clicking a link

Tags: hyperlink, click, countdown, launch

I'm a newbie on javascript and I can't figure out how I can get a countdown started after clicking a link. 
To explain I have made a simple version of what I mean. 
This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="module.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<a href="http://www.google.com" title="google.com" target="_blank">google.com</a>

<div id="countdown" class="timer">

    </div>     

</body>
</html>
```

and this is the countdown script:

```
    function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays)
{
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime()+(exdays*24*60*60*1000));
var expires = "expires="+d.toGMTString();
document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}
function getCookie(cname)
{
var name = cname + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) 
  {
  var c = ca[i].trim();
  if (c.indexOf(name)==0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
  }
return "";
}

//check existing cookie
cook=getCookie("my_cookie");

if(cook==""){
   //cookie not found, so set seconds=60
   var seconds = 120;
}else{
     seconds = cook;
     console.log(cook);
}

function secondPassed() {
    var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60);
    var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
    if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
        remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds; 
    }
    //store seconds to cookie
    setCookie("my_cookie",seconds,5); //here 5 is expiry days

    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" +    remainingSeconds;
    if (seconds == 0) {
        clearInterval(countdownTimer);
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Click again";
    } else {    
        seconds--;
    }
}

var countdownTimer = setInterval(secondPassed, 1000);
```

Is there some hero who can help me out? I hope the answer is simple but I can't figure it out....

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

> Hi Bert-Jan Groeneveld,
>
> Kindly find my below given code. Hope you may get your solutions.
>
> var minutes = 59;
>         var seconds = 59;
>
> ```
>   function setCustomTimer()
>   {
>     setInterval(showtimer, 1000);
>     return false;
>   }
>
>   function showtimer() {
>     if(seconds == 00)
>     {
>       seconds = 60;
>       minutes--;
>     }
>     seconds--;
>
>     document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" +    seconds;
>   }
> </script>   </head>   <body> 
> <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="setCustomTimer(60,59)" title="google.com" >google.com</a>
> <div id="countdown" class="timer"></div>   </body> </html>
> ```
>
> Still if you think you require more please let me know.
>
> Regards, Vimal